# PendingIntent throughout multiple Instances

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, multiple-instances

I have implemented an Alarm class wich should set a new pending Intent and always overriwrite the old one. (I would rather stop/delete all old ones but I dont know how to)

```
private void startAlarm(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(source, Alarm_Activity.class);
    // 10000 should be the ID of Intent
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(source, 10000, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)source.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
}
```

Unfortionatly I create this class multiple times and from different activities. I think this is the reason why it doesnt cancel the last intent (Flag_cancel_current). How can I make the Flag work throughout multiple instances of this class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your code, so long as all places are using the same `Intent` (pointing to `Alarm_Activity.class`) and are using the same `PendingIntent` ID (`10000` in your sample), your code will cancel any current `PendingIntent`.

This does *not* cancel any current *alarms*.

To cancel an alarm, call `cancel()` on `AlarmManager`. In particular, if you do this, get rid of `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`, so your cancelling of the old `PendingIntent` does not somehow interfere with your cancelling of the old alarm tied to that `PendingIntent`.

Comment: OK, so you would call the Method Alarmmanager.cancel(). But this needs a pending Intent that it can calcel (not just the ID).
How can I access this PendingIntent from a nother class if I have already closed the class creating the PendingIntent?
Im looking for a "magic" funktion like Alarmmanager.cancelALL()..

Comment: @user2379370: Correct. You create a `PendingIntent` with the same ID, same operation (e.g., activity) and an equivalent `Intent`. By "equivalent", I mean that the action, component, categories, MIME type, and data (`Uri`) are the same. Hence, your first two lines of your sample code should be fine to cancel an alarm established via that same sort of `PendingIntent` from before.

Comment: I tried to do it your way, but it didnt work.
I guess its because 
`PendingIntent.getActivity(**source**, 10000, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);`
needs to have the same source, but in my case it hasnt. Can I manipulate the compare(intent) operator or is there a better way?

Comment: @user2379370: Please re-read the last paragraph of my answer. Then please remove `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` and try again.

Comment: Thank you, I overread that. What flag do you recommend? All of them influence the last intent in some way.

Comment: @user2379370: Pass `0` (i.e., no flag).

Comment: Thank you!! It worked (tried 3 days)!
Btw it worked with `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`